# SHAP with Keras model : operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,6) (10,)

Tags: r, keras, shap

I am running SHAP from the library shapper in R for a classification model intrepetation on a Keras CNN model:

```
library(keras)
library("shapper")
library("DALEX")
```

I made a simple reproductible example

```
mdat.train <- cbind(rep(1:2, each = 5), matrix(c(1:30), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
train.conv <- array_reshape(mdat.train[,-1], c(nrow(mdat.train[,-1]), ncol(mdat.train[,-1]), 1))

mdat.test <- cbind(rep(1:2, each = 3), matrix(c(1:18), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
test.conv <- array_reshape(mdat.test[,-1], c(nrow(mdat.test[,-1]), ncol(mdat.test[,-1]), 1))
```

My CNN model

```
model.CNN <- keras_model_sequential()
model.CNN %>% 
  layer_conv_1d(filters=16L, kernel_initializer=initializer_he_normal(seed=NULL), kernel_size=2L, input_shape = c(dim(train.conv)[[2]],1)) %>%
  layer_batch_normalization() %>%
  layer_activation_leaky_relu() %>%

  layer_flatten() %>%
  layer_dense(50, activation ="relu") %>%
  layer_dropout(rate=0.5) %>%
  layer_dense(units=2, activation ='sigmoid')

model.CNN %>% compile(
  loss = loss_binary_crossentropy,
  optimizer = optimizer_adam(lr = 0.001, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-08),
  metrics = c("accuracy"))

model.CNN %>% fit(
  train.conv, mdat.train[,1], epochs = 5, verbose = 1)
```

My Shap command

```
p_function <- function(model, data) predict(model.CNN, test.conv, type = "prob")
exp_cnn <- explain(model.CNN, data = train.conv)
ive_cnn <- shap(exp_cnn, data = train.conv, new_observation = test.conv, predict_function = p_function)
```

I am getting this error :

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,6) (10,) 

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/shap/explainers/kernel.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.fnull = np.sum((model_null.T * self.data.weights).T, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem You've presented has two steps. First of all shown error comes from code typo. `p_function` shown by You calls global objects instead of passed ones. Thats why You have witnessed that error.

But to my surpirse I've found package not working even after clarifying that mistake. Let me explain motivation and the solution.

Have to say that 3D Arrays are not common in R, therefore shapper package does not support that type of train data. It assumes data.frame format at the beginning of the task (because it's iterating over variables). To be honest it took me like 2 hourse to find a reason why it is not working as well as a solution.

First of all we need new variables that are understandable for shapper.

```
shapper_data <- as.data.frame(train.conv)
shapper_new_obs <- as.data.frame(test.conv)[1,]
```

as well as new predict_function

```
p_function <- function(model, data) {
  mat <- as.matrix(data)
  mat <- array_reshape(mat, c(nrow(data), ncol(data), 1))
  predict(model, mat, type = "prob")
}
```

Two new lines will convert data.frame into proper shaped array.

Then line

```
ive_cnn <- individual_variable_effect(x = model.CNN, data = shapper_data, new_observation = shapper_new_obs, predict_function = p_function)
```

Works perfectly fine for me.

Best
Szymon